# Extracting dates using regex following several formats

Tags: python, regex, date

```
(?:\d{1,2}[\-\/])?(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)?[\,\.\s]*(?:\d{1,2}[\-\/\.)\s,]*)+(?:\d{2,4})(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)?[\,\.\s]*(?:\d{1,2}[\-\/\.),]*)
```

I was trying to extract dates from the text from these ff. format:

- January 1, 2020
- January 01, 2020
- JANUARY 1, 2020
- JANUARY 01, 2020
- Jan. 1, 2020
- Jan. 01, 2020
- JAN. 1, 2020
- JAN. 01, 2020
- 2020 January 1
- 2020 January 01
- 2020 Jan. 1
- 2020 Jan. 01
- 2020 JAN. 1
- 2020 JAN. 01
- 01/01/2020
- 2020/01/01
- 01.01.2020
- 2020.01.01
- 01-01-2020
- 2020-01-01

Here's a [sample](https://regex101.com/r/IJKixG/3). The problem is when it tries to extract from this format `2020 JAN. 1` , `2020 JAN. 01`, `2020 Jan. 01`, `2020-01-01`.

Comment: I wouldn't do this with one regex, but with one regex per sample/ format.

Comment: The texts are from document, it is extracted using tesseract. Date formats can be any of the following mentioned above. How would I do it your way? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
pattern = r"""(?ix)
  \b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|June?|July?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(?:Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?) [\s.]* (?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) [\s,.]* (?:19|20)(?:\d{2})? # Jan 01 2000
|
  (?<!\d)(?:19|20)(?:\d{2})? [\s,.]* (?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|June?|July?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(?:Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?) [\s.]* (?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) # 2000 Jan 01
|
 (?<!\d)
   (?:
    (?:0?[1-9]|1[012])[-/.]?(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-/.]?(?:19|20)\d\d # MM/dd/yyyy
     |
    (?:19|20)\d\d[-/.]?(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])[-/.]?(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) # yyyy/MM/dd
   )
 (?!\d)"""
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/289KKa/1)

The `i` modifier flag enables case insensitive matching and `x` enables the VERBOSE mode.

Comment: It matches `FEB-200` and `02 February 2`

Comment: @MattMateo Better now? Please adjust the pattern as you see fit, we do not see all your data.